# "Reverse lookup" in DNS zone text file

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns

Is there an existing tool or a cool or interesting way to find all items in DNS zone file, which are "resolving" to given IP? (not using any DNS server at all)

For instance, we might have following not very well organised DNS config:

```
        example.org. 60 IN A     10.0.0.1
    new.example.org. 60 IN A     10.0.0.10            
    www.example.org. 60 IN CNAME example.org.
    old.example.org. 60 IN CNAME www.example.org.
toaster.example.org. 60 IN CNAME bigbox.example.org.
cutebox.example.org. 60 IN A     new.example.org.
 bigbox.example.org. 60 IN A     10.0.0.1
```

The tool's answer to the question: `10.0.0.1` should be the set `example.org, www.example.org, old.example.org, toaster.example.org, bigbox.example.org`

**UPDATE**: to be clear: we HAVE that zone file for the domain available

**UPDATE**: the following script which i've just kludged does almost exactly what i wanted (expects dns zone file on stdin) (no IPv6 support yet :-P) :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import re
import sys

cols = (0, 4)
type_col = 3
types = ('A', 'CNAME')

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    sys.exit('query not given (IP or hostname)')

query = sys.argv[1]

rex_not = re.compile(r'^\s*;')

relations = []
found = set([query])

def filter_pairs(l, f):
    for itm in l:
        if itm[1] in f: yield itm

in_pairs = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    if rex_not.match(line): continue
    itms = re.split(r'\s+', line.strip())
    try:
        typ = itms[type_col]
        if typ not in types: continue
        a, b = (itms[cols[0]], itms[cols[1]])
    except IndexError: continue
    if a and b: in_pairs.append((a, b))

oldpairs = in_pairs[:]

while True:
    pairs = list(filter_pairs(in_pairs, found))
    for itm in pairs: found.add(itm[0])
    if len(pairs) == len(oldpairs): break
    oldpairs = pairs

found = found.difference(set([query]))

for x in found: print(x)
```

Comment: I'd say grep "10\.0\.0\.1" zonefile but maybe i misunderstood the question

Comment: Eric DANNIELOU: did you try actually grepping it and comparing with the expexted result ?

Comment: No. I guess there will be some issues. But did I understand the question correctly? I was afraid you have no direct access to zonefile

Comment: Eric DANNIELOU: yes, we have that zone file.. how it could be done with following the condition *not using any DNS server at all* ?

Comment: What's missing you (except ipv6) in the script you posted? I got the expected result (5 hosts)

Comment: Eric DANNIELOU: i thought there could be some util bundled to some dns software, which would process it properly (correct wildcards handling, etc..)

Comment: If you like python, dnspython can provide some code

Answer (score 3):

It can't be done unless there's a reverse DNS entry for each one. Sure some people will tell you that it can be done and will even point you to a bunch of web sites that claim to do it but the fact is that it's just not possible.

Comment: err, in t he meantime, i've made little script, which does it (can't handle wildcards yet) - it's about text processing and relation evaluation.. maybe i should have formulated the question better

Comment: @mykhal, No you haven't. All you've created is a script that for some tests will appear to be successful. That's like the weather office getting it right one day. It doesn't mean they'll get it right every day.

Comment: John Gardeniers: ok, what if i don't want REAL reverse lookup, but to find hostnames, which would resolve to given IP?

Comment: Do you have any idea how many hostnames there are? No. It can't be done. It really is that simple.

Comment: John Gardeniers: this one is only 7 lines long, as you can see. the question is dealing single 1st level domain, with zone file available (i have updated the question, for clarity)

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood the question. If you're looking at only doing it for a single zone file then you only need a few lines of Perl.